# Pass data from FormulateForm to a mapped action using Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-formulate

I'm currently using Vue Formulate to pass data, using `@submit="login"` on a `FormulateForm`, to a `login(data)` function.
Everything's working nicely as long as I keep the logic inside the component and I can send the `data` to my server using axios.

Thing is, I would like to put this login function in my Vuex store, as an action, but when I refer the `@submit="login"` from `FormulateForm` to the `...mapActions(["login"])` function, there is no data passed inside.
I logged `data` in the `login(data)` action, and I get this:

[Response from console.log(data) in the vuex module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2oGw.png)

I could bind values from my inputs into the store and get them from there, but I'd prefer to keep this simple and use `@submit`.

Is it at all possible to do so?

Overview of the actual code that is working:

```js
methods: {
  login(data) {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login", data, {
        withCredentials: true
      })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          this.setUserRole(res.data.isAdmin);
          this.$router.push("/");
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err.response.status === 404) {
          // TODO: gestion d'erreur
        } else if (err.response.status === 401) {
          // TODO: gestion d'erreur
        }
      });
  }
)
```

```html
<FormulateForm @submit="login">
```

Overview of what I want, that is not working:

```js
methods: {
  ...mapActions(["login"])
)
```

```html
<FormulateForm @submit="login">
```

Inside Vuex module user.js:

```js
const actions = {
  login: data => {
    console.log(data);
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login", data, { withCredentials: true })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          this.setUserRole(res.data.isAdmin);
          this.$router.push("/");
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err.response.status === 404) {
          // TODO: gestion d'erreur
        } else if (err.response.status === 401) {
          // TODO: gestion d'erreur
        }
      });
  }
};
```

As stated, the `console.log(data)`does not return my `FormulateForm` values as it does currently.

Comment: Please post more code so that you can receive help.

Comment: I updated my post. Hope it's clearer to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not dispatch the action `login`.

Do this

```js
<FormulateForm @submit="handleLogin">
```

```js
methods: {
  ...mapActions(["login"]), // here, you have mapped `this.login()` to this.$store.dispatch('login')
  handleLogin(data) {
    this.login(data);  // pass data as a parameter
  }
)
```

Then your vuex user.js store should be changed to

```js
const actions = {
  login: ({commit, state}, data) => { // it takes two arguments here
    console.log(data);
  }
};
```

For more on actions, please check the Vuex [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html)

Do these things and it should work.

Comment: I'm getting this error:

`[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

found in

---> <FormulateForm>
       <Login> at src/views/Login.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>`

Comment: I suspect it's because you are using the name `login` as the action and `login` as the method that fires the action, so it just fires itself till the stack is blown. I have updated it, @Gvrthz. It should work now.

Comment: Ah, right! I tried that earlier with a "submitHandler" name... :)
Doesn't work still...
I logged `data` in the handler function and my form values are there, but in the Vuex store when I log data at the beginning of my function, there's still nothing but this "weird" object (for me who's a beginner).

Comment: Please post your full Vuex module, user.js. I think your syntax may be wrong.

Comment: [user.js Vuex module](https://pastebin.com/YJ8Fqgdu) Hope this is it! Can't wrap my head around it... :(

Comment: As I suspected, you were logging the object containing commit and state objects. I have updated my answer, @Gvrthz.

Comment: Ok, this works perfectly... I didn't understand the need for two parameters, but now I do. Actions always need a `state` and a `payload` because they commit one or more mutations... Seems logic. Thank you for you QUICK help.